# Using Junit assert on json array of elements fails on first element

Tags: arraylist, junit, assert, katalon-studio, jsonslurper

I'm trying to use Katalon Studio for some webservice automation. I have been following this guide on how to parse returned Json body using jsonslurper.
`https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/tutorials/parse_json_responses.html`
Everything is working fine as described in the guide. I wanted to see if I can use junit asserts, specifically the assertEquals() for better error text.
Given we have this

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

String jsonString = {"menu": {
"id": "file",
"tools": {
"actions": [
{"id": "new", "title": "New File"},
{"id": "open", "title": "Open File"},
{"id": "close", "title": "Close File"}
],
"errors": []
}}}
JsonSlurper slurper = new JsonSlurper()
Map parsedJson = slurper.parseText(jsonString)

def array1 = parsedJson.menu.tools.actions

String onlickValue1 = ""

for(def member : array1) {
assertEquals("Open File", member.title)
break
}
```

What I'm having trouble with, is that my assert will thrown an error when comparing the very first title element it encounters (which is "New File").

What I intend is to loop through all the elements in the array and assert my expected value against all of them. If my expected value doesn't exist, then I'd fail.

I feel like I'm missing something, because we've done something similar in the past with java, but I just can't see it here.

Comment: What errors do you get when you run this code?  Triple quotes at the end of your code snippet shouldn't be there. And the json parsing looks off.

Comment: Apologies, the triple quotes were my attempt to style the code when I was writing the message. The error message I'm getting is my assertion fails on the very first `title` element in the actions array. Which I now understand is due to my confusion of the logic in my code (was using for.each loop to compare each element in the array and it was failing correctly). I will close this question and ask what I'm trying to solve in a different way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out the problem was my inexperience/ignorance. When looking for solutions online I failed to understand with absolute certainty what the code I'm trying to implement is doing. I was using a for.each loop to assert elements in the array against my expected value. Which of course was failing, correctly, for every element that didn't match my expected value. So I made it work by adding an `if` statement as below:

```
String expectedValue = ''
for(def member : array1) {
if (member.title=="Open File")
{
expectedValue = member.title
}
break
}
assertEquals("Open File", member.title)
```

Also a simpler way I discovered is to use `assertJ` in the following way
`assertThat(member).contains("Open File")`

I understand there are better solutions to achieve what I'm trying to do. But for purposes of this question I considered it solved.